# How do I get my NSString from object?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have some text fields. E.g. this one

```
TTMessageField *field = [fields objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%S", field.description);
NSLog(@"%@", field);
```

[**TTMessageField Class Reference.**](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_field.php)

The second line prints

```
To: (
    "recipient"
)
```

and the third

```
To: (\n    recipient\n)
```

I am not sure why but the description does not return the recipient only. It is wrapped by this To:() like you see above.

```
- (NSString*)description {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _title];
}
```

Is it possible to extract just the recipient? Something like

```
NSString *str = field.description;
```

and then use a regex to get the recipient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could change `TTMessageField` to `TTMessageRecipientField` which **extends** TTMessageField.
TTMessageRecipientField has a field recipients which is an NSArray and holds the names of the recipients:

```
TTMessageRecipientField *field = [fields objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *recipient = [field recipients];
NSString *str = [recipient objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using other method name than "description"? In fact **-description** method is NSObject's method and causes any object to print its values. There might be some kind of overriding interference there, give a try to some other name, "-descriptionString" for instance.

Comment: descriptionString does not exist. I added a reference to the class in my question

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you're using Three20 for this. Try this

```
TTMessageField *field = [fields objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myString = [field title];
```

Comment: Yes I use three20, but your example prints just "To:"